# how to know entire stored procedure call hierarchy which is inserting/updating/deleting my table data

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Im using sql server 2008 R2, and I have a bunch of stored procedures (i'm not sure what exactly the logic written in each procedure). All these procedures directly or indirectly interact with my table data.

Now how can I know which table has made the changes (inserts/updates/deletes) on my table data.

For example, the stored procedures are as follows

```
  Proc1
  {
    insert into MyTable()
  }

  Proc2
  {
    update MyTable()
    Proc3()
  }

  Proc3
  {
    delete MyTable()
  }

  DoSomethingProc()
  {
    if (condition1)
      Proc1()
    else if (condition2 and condition3)
      Proc2()
  }
```

Now once, DoSomethingProc is called, MyTable data is inserted/updated/deleted. So when condition1 satisfied, I want the hierarchy as DoSomethingProc->Proc1 and when condition2 and condition3 satisfied, then I want the hierarchy as DoSomethingProc->Proc2->Proc3

Can this be achieved in sql server. I was trying with trigger by throwing error and fetching the error stack, but could not succeed. Please help.